# Is there any chances for loss in user requests in DHCP server?

Tags: server, vps, dhcp

I have doubt while making my router as DHCP server that is:
suppose I made my router a DHCP server and I have connected one computer to the router which will listen to all the user requests now I have added more devices like mobile phones etc. But till now as we know we have only one device (server) which listens to user requests my question is, Is there any possibility that because of all other devices my server won't able to get user requests? I know question can be silly for you I want to know the answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP protocol has an explicit mechanism for packet loss. Clients are supposed to do a retry on renew or fall back to start over with discover messages. If there is one more computer on the network is probably less important than the number of clients trying to renew their IP address at the same time. I have seen networks with 70,000 devices managed by a single DHCP server with no problem. Of course the DHCP server needs to be fast in all aspects: network latency, storage speed (for the lease data base) and processing speed. If the question is whether the DHCP protocol traffic can hinder other protocols? Then the answer is potentially yes, but probably only at times when many device go online (and need an IP address) at the same time. The overall traffic on the network generally is most likely not influenced by the very small amount of data single DHCP messages create.